# On inequalities and the binomial theorem

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b$ be real number such that $0 < a < b $,

Does it follow that

$$ b^n -a^n < (b-a)nb^{n-1} $$

????

Can we still have this result if we only require $a < b$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(\underbrace{a^{n-1}}_{\leq b^{n-1}}+b\underbrace{a^{n-2}}_{\leq b^{n-2}}+...+b^{n-1})<(a-b)nb^{n-1}$$

But notice that $a^n-b^n<0$ whereas $(b-a)nb^{n-1}>0$ therefore the inequality is obviously correct, I suppose that the left term is $b^n-a^n$, no ?